# Split a dataframe into list of dataframes after each event

Tags: r

How to split a dataframe into list of dataframes after each event? I have the same user in this example.

```
    tibble(
  from = c("user", "operator", "operator", "operator","user","operator","operator","user","operator","operator"),
  type = c("text", "text", "text", "event","text","text","event","text","text","text"))
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data is in a data.frame called `d`:

```
# find rows where the _previous_ row contained "event"
d$check_for_event = dplyr::lag(d$type, default = "") == "event"
# take cumsum to create increment column
d$cumu_check_for_event <- cumsum(d$check_for_event)
# use split to create a list of data.frames based on increment column
split(d, d$cumu_check_for_event)

$`0`
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  from     type  check_for_event cumu_check_for_event
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>                          <int>
1 user     text  FALSE                              0
2 operator text  FALSE                              0
3 operator text  FALSE                              0
4 operator event FALSE                              0

$`1`
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  from     type  check_for_event cumu_check_for_event
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>                          <int>
1 user     text  TRUE                               1
2 operator text  FALSE                              1
3 operator event FALSE                              1

$`2`
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  from     type  check_for_event cumu_check_for_event
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>                          <int>
1 user     text  TRUE                               2
2 operator text  FALSE                              2
3 operator text  FALSE                              2
```

Comment: Base R: `rev(unname(split(dat, rev(cumsum(rev(dat$type) == "event")))))` (the outer `rev(unname(...))` are because the frames and their numbers will be in reverse ... though structurally the same frames).

Comment: what is default argument in `lag`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in dplyr:

```
  df %>% 
  mutate(check_for_event = lag(type, default = "") == "event") %>%
  mutate(cum_check = cumsum(check_for_event)) %>% 
  split(.$cum_check)
```

Thanks to [bouncyball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5619526/bouncyball).